# How to calculate current scroll position in list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying with pure javascript to get the current scroll position and save it.

After that, I want to scroll it to the saved/current scroll position.

On the list is attached `onScroll` event, this function is called on event:

```
// I wanted to get a scrolled position and scroll it into that position
handleScrollPosition = (e) => {
  const container = document.getElementById(this.props.id);
  container.scrollTo(container.offsetLeft - e.scrollOffset, container.offsetTop - e.scrollOffset);
};
```

But this not work as expected, any advice on how to handle this?

Comment: Please, try `document.body.scrollTop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

**Get or set the horizontal and vertical scroll position of an element or the document.**

Use the properties `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` to get or set the scroll position of an element:

`var el = document.querySelector('div');`

**get scroll position in px**

`console.log(el.scrollLeft, el.scrollTop);`

**set scroll position in px**

`el.scrollLeft = 500;`

`el.scrollTop = 1000;`

**Getting the scroll position of the document in px.**

```
var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

**Setting the document scroll position of the document in px:**

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = 1000;
document.documentElement.scrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft = 500;
```

More information 
https://plainjs.com/javascript/styles/get-and-set-scroll-position-of-an-element-26/